# Programmatically download a Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs-api

Google Docs have a "Download as..." menu option, with several choices of format such as PDF, text, etc.

How can I programmatically download a particular Google document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [how to programmatically download a public Google Drive file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215210/how-to-programmatically-download-a-public-google-drive-file):

> You don't need any Google SDK if you know the link and the file is public. Just use a standard HTTP GET method to download the file.

Example with AngularJS:

```
$http.get('/doc_url').
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```